# do I really need to specify the php head content-type?

Tags: php, header, content-type

I have both .mp3 and .pcm audio format on my server, how should I set the php header content-type when I don't know which type the user has requested for?

Comment: How *could* you not know which type the user has requested for?

Comment: i CAN know, but in my system, the user's request doesnt contain the audio format info, i need to retrieve that info from db, so i m seeking if there is a simple way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can just use "Application/octet-stream" for any type of binary file format.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to .. you can use [`mime_content_type`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) to  Detect MIME Content-type for a file simplify the process in your header

Example

```
header(sprintf('Content-type: %s',mime_content_type($filename)));
```

Comment: Why not use simple string concatenation? `header('Content-type: .mime_content_type($filename));`

Answer (score 0):

When you say you set the header the i think your rewrite your **.mp3** and **.pcm** to a PHP-Script.

In this case you should rewrite it with the file extension. Then you can check the extension in your **$_GET** variable.

```
if(strpos('.mp3', $_GET['filename']) !== false) {
   header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename="test.mp3"');
}

if(strpos('.pcm', $_GET['filename']) !== false) {
   header("Content-type: application/octet-stream;");
}
```

PCM data is RAW-Data so i think you can use **octet-stream** or the cool solution from Baba

So you can check which format it is and set the header for the specified file.

Here is another post to this problem: 
[Output mp3 with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275126/output-mp3-with-php)

Comment: What if `$_GET['filename'] = "a.mp3.pcm"`?

Answer (score 0):

In my site i used this type of header. I suggests this one.

Example

header("content-type:text/xml;charset=utf-8;charset=windows-1256");