# echo a string in html tag <audio>

Tags: php, html, mysql, audio

can somebody please tell me what's wrong with my code ?! i stored the file path in my database as `varchar` and it's 01.mp3 and the file is right next to the php file but it's not working and i'm using Mysql 
here's the function file getAudio.php

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';
// to connect with the database
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  // validation just to be safe

  $sql = "SELECT file FROM filepath WHERE id=$id"; 
  // choose the column from the table where the id= the id of the audio file

  $result = mysql_query("$sql");
  //query the audio file

  $row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  //Returns an associative array

  mysql_close($link);
  //closes the non-persistent connection to the MySQL



 echo $row['file'];
 //calls the audio file and returns it in the src attribute
?>
```

and here's where i'm trying to echo it song.php

```
<?php
include 'conn.php'; ?> 

<html> 
<head><title></title></head>
<body>


<audio controls> 
<source src="<?php echo '/getAudio.php?id=1/';?>" type="audio/mpeg"> 


</audio>




</body>
</html>
```

and when i replace the `''` with `""` the audio appears but it doesn't play

Comment: You probably need to change the header on the php page to the right filetype before `echo $row['file'];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output mp3 with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275126/output-mp3-with-php)

Comment: @Terminus you mean to type 'header("Content-type: text/plain"); '

Answer (score 0):

```
<source src="<?php echo '/getAudio.php?id=1/';?>" type="audio/mpeg">
```

You don't need PHP here, juste write it in HTML without the last "/" :

```
<source src="/getAudio.php?id=1" type="audio/mpeg">
```

If it does not work, just call "/getAudio.php?id=1" from your browser and see what happens (error ? bad filename ? etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to integrate or change this in your code:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
$song = file_get_contents("01.mp3");//your song directory
?>

<audio controls="controls">
    <source src="<?php echo $song; ?>"  />
</audio>
```