# Is it possible to protect audio file with PHP?

Tags: php, audio, passwords, mp3, drm

I'm trying to add on my site new feature. I want people to download audio files but files must be protected somehow (password?). Only one person (account owner) could listen to this file. Is is even possible?

Comment: Do you want to let users to download the mp3 or just to listen online?

Comment: you can create albom for user audio file and develop access for this albom by password, user id, frands no frands and other methods...

Comment: check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222532/protect-audio-file-from-being-downloaded-while-still-being-playable-through-jque

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. For this make for example a file called `audio.php` in this one you check the user permission and then set the headers to send an audio file and output the audio file afterwards, if the permission is not approved show an access denied.

How the audio headers are done is discribed here: [Output mp3 with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275126/output-mp3-with-php)

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I know how to let download/listen file for one user but after this user can send audi file to another user. I want to somehow protect audio file and let only one person listen to. Like some antypiracy software or something.

Comment: You can't achieve this with php, you will most likely need your own audio format + player that validates the license for this, can't think of any other way

Comment: Okay. So another question. Are there any way to hide path to file on website? The solution will be to listen files only online, but somebody could see the source of file and see path to file and download it.

Comment: Sadly when you're in the web every obfuscasion of the path would be reverseable somehow